Think before closing question
I just asked a question at math stack exchange and someone kindly gave me an answer. I wanted to continue discussion but some cruel guy closed the question instantly and it no longer is available.
A guy already had spent some of his time with it writing a response for me.
A new rule concerning closing question be added: Once a question gets a relatively good response which seems to have taken a relatively much amount of effort, the question no longer be closed.
Closing question instantly is deleting efforts of the volunteer instantly.
Another guy gave me a reference on some rule by which my question is going to be closed. But it is too long to read and the question was made not available even before finishing to read the long rule.
Make math stack exchange moderated group, and then I might not ask questions there anymore.
But in the first place, be more friendly. Who cares about questions being of lower quality? That long rule is not necessary, is my second suggestion.

"Who cares about questions being of lower quality?" - pretty much everyone here and on the rest of the network - including the staff of the company that runs it. Except apparently yourself....?

Do you mean "closing" or "deleting"? They're different things - one only blocks new answers, while the other deletes the question and its answers entirely.

Could you please provide a link to your question?

@Starship Well, sure that they're in business to make money, but quality is the brand that they're selling - they care about preserving the brand's market share. As far as I can tell.

We all use AI (translation was my first active participation with it), it's a fact of the modern world, unavoidable in some form or other. How it's to be used (or misgivings/anticipation of how) is the main point of disagreement as far as I can tell. @Starship It's all rather up in the air as to what will happen re. regulation and copyright laws and AI. I'm waiting to see, optimistically (possibly misguided)

@W.O. I mean overriding community policy and allowing posting of fully AI written posts.

Are they doing that? I thought it was still banned on many (if not most/all) sites. That being said, I've used AI gen images to illustrate a point in answers on W/B. That seems to be acceptable and not replace human creativity but augment it. @Starship

@W.O. They're not but they did last year...

Testing community feeling perhaps (without explicitly stating it's a test)? Maybe I'm projecting too much of the marketing-Machiavellianism on them that I see in UK politicians. @Starship Presumably, the fact they didn't override the community proved that they listen. Inclusivity exercise then...?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you want to dispute the closure of your question (and/or its deletion; it's not entirely clear what happened to your question, since you haven't provided a link), you should do so on Math.SE's own Meta site. This one is for issues that affect the entire network.

@security_paranoid Already asked above (also question in question is confusing...but not as confusing as "can you please settle the question of the question in question without question as to make there be no question about the question in question")

@sozinhozinho If you're referring to this question on mathematics, please note that it isn't a question, you've stated no actual question there. You've not stated what the problem is that you're trying to solve, nor have you stated what you yourself have tried to solve it. Perhaps go to the mathematics site's help centre and familiarize yourself with the site's standards, then re-word the question to fit them. After that, go to mathematics meta to resolve any issues.

Ironically, this question has been closed.

"I wanted to continue discussion but some cruel guy closed the question instantly and it no longer is available.". SE sites are not a discussion site or forum. We are a Q&A, remember the motto objective questions for specific problems and without distractions.


Think before closing question

Closers already think before closing or voting to close a question. Any who don’t are robo-reviewers and should (and usually are) review-banned.

A new rule concerning closing question be added: Once a question gets a relatively good response which seems to have taken a relatively much amount of effort, the question no longer be closed.

This is a terrible idea. This would encourage people to waste their time to provide a good response to a bad question to avoid it being closed, discourage users to actually make good questions, and potentially let more users waste their time answering the question.
In addition, how will you judge how good an answer is? Voting is an okay method but it’s not perfect. Plenty of good answers don’t get upvoted and sometimes bad answers get upvoted. And certainly I don’t know how one would judge how much effort an answer took.

Closing question instantly is deleting efforts of the volunteer instantly.

Closing is not deleting. It is (temporarily) preventing answers to your question. If you fix the question, it will be reopened.

But it is too long to read

Do you seriously expect someone to put in the effort to do you a favor and answer your question if you can’t put in the effort to actually read a page?

Make math stack exchange moderated group, and then I might not ask questions there anymore.

Math Stack Exchange and every other site is already moderated. If that makes you not want to ask questions, while not great, that’s not going to change that fact or any other rule.

Who cares about questions being of lower quality?

People who want to build a high-quality Q&A site, which is (ideally) everyone contributing to the site.

That long rule is not necessary

Maybe before saying “this rule isn’t necessary you should at least bother to read it.

The OP says “closed” but when they mention it being “not available”, it makes me think their question could have gotten deleted instead.

@fyrepenguin They could have also meant "not available to answer" but I get what you're saying...thats why the OP should link to their question

@fyrepenguin I think this is the question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4989849/an-inequality-for-binomial-coefficients

I did see that question, but it was asked (and closed) almost a month ago, and also has no comments (currently). That’s why I’m not so sure that it’s the same question referenced, seeing as they say “I  just asked a question at math stack exchange“ and while it’s possible that they still consider a month ago as “just”, the lack of a more recent question plus the term “unavailable” made me think there could be a more recent deleted question. I see you’ve already directly asked for a link to the post in question, so we’ll see which interpretation was correct.

@fyrepenguin They could have meant that they closure thing at the top told them to read something (which is actually quite long in fairness).

I think I've found the question (dramatic music plays.)

The other answer does a great job at explaining why questions of low quality, etc. should be closed, but I want to try address your question specifically, to help you in the future.
Your question is one small sentence with an inequality formula, but you haven't actually asked anything.
As per the reason for closure states:

additional context

is needed.

Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Your question has none of these.

Now, I probably sound quite harsh, grilling your question, but every Stacks could benefit from more high quality posts. The Math SE help centre is a great place to start, but for you it seems you have already, in the past, asked some relatively well-taken questions.
And again, your other questions are paragraphs long, with context. This question just isn't.

Now, there two thing you can do:

If this question can include context, edit it, and it could get re-opened.

But if it simply can't, just accept that it's off-topic.



I don't know if that's the right post. It's pretty old, and OP said that they "just" asked the question at hand.

@Anerdw hmm, you might be right, I hadn’t considered that. But I think my answer still applies. The same principles still apply. Let’s ask the OP themselves.
